# Application crushed : terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm programming an application in Swift and Objective-C and when I run the test app on the iPhone everything works, but when i was trying to start a call the application crashed showing this:

```
 *** First throw call stack:
   (0x181be11b8 0x18061855c 0x181be1100 0x182610eb8 0x100265a2c 0x187acbd30 0x187acbcb0 0x187ab6128 0x187acb59c 0x187acb0c4 0x187ac6328 0x187a96da0 0x18828075c 0x18827a130 0x181b8eb5c 0x181b8e4a4 0x181b8c0a4 0x181aba2b8 0x18356e198 0x187b017fc 0x187afc534 0x1002bc898 0x180a9d5b8)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) terminating
```

This is the button code:

```
   - (IBAction)startCallButton:(id)sender {

TCallViewController *callViewController = [[TCallViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:callViewController animated:YES];
 NSString *handle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:_handle];
 BOOL Video = _video;
 if ((handle = callViewController.handle) ){
 Video = callViewController.video;
[callManager startCallWithHandle:(handle) video:Video];

 }
   }
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Cant debug if you dont give the code of `TCallViewController ` or atleast `startCallWithHandle`

Comment: After `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) terminating` There is no more message?

Comment: @Tj3n here ise the code of StartCall:                                                    
 func startCall(handle: String, video: Bool = false) {
        let handle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
        let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: handle)
        
        startCallAction.isVideo = video
        
        let transaction = CXTransaction()
        transaction.addAction(startCallAction)
        
        requestTransaction(transaction)
    }

Comment: @Larme yes that's all

Comment: make sure none of the value is nil by putting breakpoint in that function and use  `po object` in your console to see it